# OpenServer блокирует отображение CSS

Tags: css, openserver

Если открываю сайт через `OpenServer`, то на сайте отображается только `html` код, а `css` невиден. Если же открываю сайт без запуска сервера, то всё отлично. Кстати говоря, такая проблема только `Google Chrome`, в остальных браузерах все норм.

Chrome переустанавливал, настройки/куки сбрасывал.

Вот логи из OpenServer:

> site.ru: 192.168.0.107 [20/Jul/2017:19:41:42 +0700] "GET /
>   HTTP/1.1" "-" 200 2562 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.86
>   Safari/537.36" "-"

Comment: Крч если обновить страницу в браузере ctrl+f5 (это обновления страницы с очиской кеширования), то стили появляются. Но это не удобно так каждый раз обновлять. Какая то херня с кэшом в хроме этом

Comment: Скорее всего у вас указан не верный путь до стилевого файла. Смотрите в консоль в хроме, какой там путь?

Comment: /favicon.ico Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Вот что выдает консоль хрома. Нет, путь к файлу прописан 100% верно

Comment: а нет, эта ошибка не связана с моей проблемой. В общем консоль хрома чиста

Comment: В `Google Chrome` какая-то шляпа с этим кэшированием и `favicon`. Лучше сразу приучить себя перезагружать страницу через `Ctrl + F5`

Comment: Подтверждаю - в хроме относительно недавно (после их очередного обновления) началась такая херня.. И это вам ещё f5 каким-то чудом помогает - мне, например, приходится время от времени делать очистку истории браузера ((

Comment: приучить нажимать ctrl+f5 себя конечно можно, но только что делать, если ты привык работать с плагином livereload (тип пишешь css код, а он подгружается без обновления страницы), который работает только в хроме